# Countif with reference to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference, range, countif

Hello I will need help with problem I am facing right now and even Google couldn't help me.

I would like to add to field `AS2` a `COUNTIF` formula with source information from different sheet.

This `COUNTIF` should jump to sheet `ee_lpk` and then take a range from column `A2` down to the end of last used row. and compare that with criteria from field `D`.

so for `AS2` will be comparing with `D2` for `AS3` with `D3`.

When I recorded that it showed:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = COUNTIF(ee_lkp!R[-143]C[-44]:R[217]C[-44],R[-143]C[-41])"
```

this is working but just in case that there is on ee_lpk page same number or rows what is changing from day to day.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Martin

Comment: Your source range in sheet ee_lkp - does the width (columns) change or could it just be the length (rows) of the sheet?

Comment: just rows.. it always take just A:A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this problem down using variables. Try something like this:

```
sub Answer()

Dim srcRng as Range
Dim srcLength as Long

'First find how many rows on sheet ee_lpk and store it as a variable
srcLength = Sheets("ee_lkp").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Then use that variable to get your range
Set srcRng = Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(srcLength, 1))
'Or another viable option would be:
'Set srcRng = Range("A2:A" & srcLength)

'Then put that in your Countif formula
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=COUNTIF(ee_lkp!" & srcRng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ", R[-143]C[-41])

End Sub
```

Comment: @Martin did this work? Please mark it as answered if it did - if it didn't, let me know what went wrong ...

Comment: it is showing Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument in that line where I set srcRng. no clue what can be wrong there as it looks logic for me

Comment: Fixed now, try the edited version. I forgot that 'A2' can only be called from the `Range()` function, not from `Cells()`

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!! Thanks a lot lot. It is working perfect now.

Comment:  no worries!!